# Slick Slide Removes Inline Styling on Responsive Breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am experiencing the same issue as seen here: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3439

The slider works fine until I resize the window to my set breakpoint, then all slides' inline styles will be overwritten. This also happens when the page is loaded past the breakpoint.

My slides are containing images set inline as background-images. They must be inline so I cannot create a class and set the background images. Has anyone else experienced this issue or know of a fix or workaround?

Comment: Can you nest the elements with the inline styles a level deeper?  It would be helpful to see what you have now.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem**

```
<div class="slider" style="background-image:url('bg.jpg');">
    <div class="insideSlider">

    </div>
</div>
```

**The Solution**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="insideSlider" style="background-image:url('bg.jpg');">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Super easy fix to a really annoying issue!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's 3 months later but I found another thread with the answer to this issue. I'm posting it here because I found this when I was searching for answer to this problem before I found the other thread.

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3439

You have to remove `originalSlides.removeAttr('style');` on line 826. It's a workaround but it works.